# Get Server to Accept Multipart Uploads for Large Files with Abort/Resume Functionality like S3

Tags: php, python, http, rest, amazon-s3

Amazon S3 has [a very nice feature](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/11/10/Amazon-S3-Introducing-Multipart-Upload/) that allows the upload of files in parts for larger files. This would be very useful to me if I was using S3, but I am not.

Here's my problem: I am going to have Android phones uploading reasonably large files (~50MB each of binary data) on a semi-regular basis. Because these phones are using the mobile network to do this, and the coverage is spotty in some of the places where they're being used, strong signal cannot be guaranteed. Therefore, doing a simple PUT with 40MB of data in the content body will not work very well. **I need to split up the data somehow (probably into 10MB chunks) and upload them whenever the signal will allow it. Once all of the chunks have been uploaded, they need to be merged into a single file.**

I have a basic understanding of how the client needs to behave to support this through reading Amazon's S3 Client APIs, but have no idea what the server is doing to allow this. I'm willing to write the server in **Python or PHP**. **Are there any libraries out there for either language to allow this sort of thing?** I couldn't find anything after about one hour of searching.

Basically, I'm looking for anything that can help point me in the right direction. Information on this and what protocols and headers to use to make this as RESTful as possible would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of creating separate files, you can "prepare" a single file by using `ftruncate()` with the desired size and then write each section inside using `fseek()` followed by `stream_copy_to_stream()` :)

Comment: Oh, interesting point! Didn't think about that one.

Comment: Hope that gives you enough ideas to venture into this yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the REST API documentation for [multi-part upload](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/11/10/Amazon-S3-Introducing-Multipart-Upload/) it seems that Amazon expects the client to break the large file into smaller multiple parts and upload them individually. Prior to uploading you need to obtain an [upload id](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadInitiate.html) and on every upload you include the upload id and the a part number for the portion of the file being uploaded.

The way you may have to go about structuring is to create a client which can split a huge file into multiple parts and upload them in parallel using the above specified convention.

Comment: What would be the best/most efficient way to store the file parts on the backend if I am to write this myself (I'm still thinking there's got to be a library for this, but I'm prepared to do the dirty work if there isn't). Better to use a database or raw files, for example?

I did read the client spec from Amazon so I understand how it works, I'm more interested in a library or else what would be the best way to implement the server.

Comment: Once the data is transferred you will recombine them and store as a single file as opposed to multiple parts. In terms managing the files transferred to the backend and storing them in either a db or a filesystem would require more context about the data and the requirements. In terms of libraries I have not come across anything specific so far.

Comment: You can take a look at the multipart implementation of boto https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/multipart.py